# Cannot remove /var/lib/docker

Tags: server, docker

I'm trying to remove docker from my Ubuntu 16.04. When coming to the step to remove all of the container files:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/containers
```

Seems like it is stuck here forever, means that there must be some process that holding this folder, is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: #lsof /var/lib/docker/containers gives what? find the pid of process which accessing the directory.

Comment: unfortunately, it gives nothing :(

Comment: Is there any error message shown?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check first if any container running with `docker ps -a`,
then do a `docker system prune -a`

Comment: These commands did not allow me to run `sudo rm -rv /var/lib/docker/aufs/` on `Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS`.